# Forked Processes and Shared variables

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have a bash script with two forked functions all writing to a log. When both have finished, I'd like to delete this log.

The problem I'm having though, is that `processFinishCount` is never greater than one. Does each forked process grab a *copy* of the shared variable and increment that copy when it calls `delete_log`?

How can I ensure the variable is incremented properly?

```
processFinishCount=0

delete_log()
{
    let processFinishCount++
    if ["$processFinishCount" == 2]; then
        rm log.txt

    else
        echo `$processFinishCount task(s) finished" >> log.txt
    fi
}

function_one()
{
    ...
    delete_log
}
function_two()
{
    ...
    delete_log
}

function_one &
function_two &
```

Comment: The variable is processFinishCount but the if statement has processCount.

Comment: Also the global variable is 0 when the fork happens. So both the forked processes will start with 0 and will increment to 1. One solution is to have the count in a file or have a status file for each forked process and test for its existence.

Comment: @jaychris, the difference in variables was just a typo.<br/>That's what I had concluded was happening. The external file is a valid solution. I'll try that when I get back to work on Monday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global variable in one process will not be updated in the other. Hence an external file could be used. I will have something like this (not checked for accuracy).

```
delete_log()
{
    touch /tmp/$1
    if [ -e $status_file1 -a -e $status_file2 ]
    then 
        rm log.txt
    else
        echo log >> log.txt
    fi
}

f1()
{
    ...
    delete_log $1
}

f2()
{
    ...
    delete_log $1
}

f1 fork1.done &
f2 fork2.done &
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `wait` to wait for all child processes to finish. This prints `a` after 3 seconds:

```
sleep 3 &
sleep 1 &
wait
echo a
```

`help wait`:

```
wait: wait [id]
    Wait for job completion and return exit status.

    Waits for the process identified by ID, which may be a process ID or a
    job specification, and reports its termination status.  If ID is not
    given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return
    status is zero.  If ID is a a job specification, waits for all processes
    in the job's pipeline.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of ID; fails if ID is invalid or an invalid option is
    given.
```

Comment: I can't use wait, the intention of forking in the first place is to get execution of the main script to finish as quickly as possible.

Comment: Yes, you can.  Put the wait in a shell function that is backgrounded, that then calls the two jobs.  Then you can return from the main script, and the subshell is doing the wait.